# Black screen flashes at the start android app

Tags: codenameone

The black screen is visible for a moment at the start of the app in android devices. I've tested in all of my recent apps and it is there. In some devices, the black screen appears a bit longer especially in oreo.

Have a look at the video [here](https://youtu.be/xQRxh7WCO50)

```
How can I solve it?
```

Answer (score 3):

This is triggered because your start method is taking too long to process the Form or the Form's rendering code is too slow. When that happens Android tries to draw your app but it takes too long and so it just shows what it has.

Remove the clutter from `start` and just show a `Form` that's a splash screen then transition to the actual app. Optimize your actual app UI by using profilers & the performance monitor tool.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, showing a splash screen before the actual app (as suggested by Shai) is a good idea to be sure that all the splash screen images generated for iOS by the Codename One build servers are as you want them: in this way, the app startup look will be very similar on iOS and Android. Some popular app, like Facebook, use a splash screen that show their icon at the middle of the screen.

However, about your question, in my "new" Android 7 device, almost "all" the apps, even the ones preinstalled with Android, show a blank screen for a fraction of second at startup. So I suppose that it's normal. That blank screen is usually white, but is some app the color of the blank startup screen is different (for example, in ES File Manager is gray). Also my Codename One apps show a blank white screen at startup (before the splash screen in the apps in which I implemented it). Maybe the color of the startup blank screen depends on the styling of the app.